# SQL Server : is it possible to find out the original user who issued setuser 'impersonate_username'?

Tags: sql-server, impersonation

SQL Server allows a login with sufficient rights to issue a `setuser` command and impersonate another user. For e.g I can connect as user1 and if I have syadmin role, I can issue a `setuser 'user2'`. Now my context gets switched to user2.

But is there any way to figure out that, using T-SQL:

1. that there is 'impersonation' going on?
2. Who the original user was i.e in this case user1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the function [ORIGINAL_LOGIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189492.aspx)().  Also, I think you'll find [sys.sysprocesses.loginame](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189492.aspx) remains constant no matter what happens with `setuser` or `execute as`.